# Cohomology of $T^n/W$ for compact Lie groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, finite-groups, character-varieties

Let $G$ be a compact, connected and simply connected Lie group. 
Let $T\subset G$ be a maximal torus and let $W$ be the corresponding 
Weyl group.

Then we have the diagonal action of $W$ on $T^{n}$ for $n\ge 0$.
I would like to know if the cohomology groups $H^{*}(T^{n}/W;\mathbb{Z})$ 
have been computed or if anything is known about them.

The case $n=1$ is particularly simple as $T/W$ is contractible 
when $G$ simply connected. However, if $n>1$, one gets a complicated space. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean singular cohomology groups of the quotient space $T^n/W$, no? How can $T/W$ be contractible, being a closed manifold?

Comment: @Mariano:  $T/W$ isn't, in general, a closed manifold since $W$ doesn't act freely on $T$.  For example, when $G = SU(2)$, $W = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts on the circle as complex conjugation.  The quotient is homeomorphic to a closed interval (and is contractible).

Comment: I mean the cohomology of the honest quotient $T^{n}/W$. When $n=1$  one can show that a closed alcove is homeomorphic to $T/W$ and thus it is contractible. For $n>1$ on gets a complicated quotient. For example when $G=SU(2)$ and $n=2$ one has $T^{2}/W$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$ and it gets more complicated for higher values of $n$.

Comment: @José Manuel Gómez I'm confused by this. I think the quotient is always contractible. The Weyl group is generated by reflections  and the Weyl chamber walls project to the boundary of the quotient $T/W$. In particular for $G=SU(3)$ the quotient is a flat triangle, not a sphere, topologically. 

Answer (score 6):

In the case $G=\mathrm{U}(m)$, this is the character variety $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n, \mathrm{U}(m))/\mathrm{U}(m)$.

See my paper [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.7616.pdf) for general results on its topology (and similar results for other compact and complex reductive $G$).

In particular, the rational cohomology ring is worked out at the end.  So from this you can at least get the free part of the integral cohomology, as discussed in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/239588/12218).

Also see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.4389.pdf) for the computation of its fundamental group.

Examples:

1. For $n=1$ and $G$ simply connected you always get closed ball.  See Remark 6.2 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.3317.pdf).
2. For $n=2$ and $G=\mathrm{SU}(2)$ you get a 2-sphere.  [Here](http://eagl.wdfiles.com/local--files/3dprinting/Orange_pillowcase.jpg) is a 3D print of it.  It is the boundary of $\mathrm{Hom}(F_2,\mathrm{SU}(2))/\mathrm{SU}(2)$.  See Example 3.14 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0781.pdf).
3. For $n=3$ and $G=\mathrm{SU}(2)$ you get 3-dimensional
   orbifold with 8 isolated singularities.  See the discussion on page 23 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.3603.pdf) for a more detailed discussion.  Also, there is this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMj4OBq0HWo) giving a visualization of this orbifold.

Answer (score 4):

The case n=2 is well studied and has beautiful anwser.  This quotient space is a weighted projective space (and for $SU(n)$ it is $CP^{n-1}$). See E. Looijenga, Root systems and elliptic curves, Invent. Math. 38 (1976), 17–32. And I.N. Bernshtein and O.V. Shvartsman, Chevalley’s theorem for complex crystallographic Cox-
eter groups, Funct. Anal. Appl. 12 (1978), 308–310.  As pointed out in Sean's answer these quotient spaces are moduli spaces of flat $G$ connections in the trivial $G$ bundle over the torus.  It is interesting to extend this story to non-trivial $G$ bundles. A wonderful book about some of what goes on "Almost commuting elements in compact Lie groups" by Borel, Friedman and Morgan.